# need of two xibs for my portrait and landscape modes

Tags: iphone, orientation

i am very new to xcode. i have an app which supports both for iphone and ipad.presently my app supports portrait orientation, now i want to support it for landscape also.

As  i goggled it and got  an idea that we have to maintain two views for that.is this is the only way to do that? can't i maintain with singleview for landscape and portrait ?

if this is only the way provide me a good tutorial to do this because i have lots of views.

Note: my app should support in ios 4,5,6 also

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO** . You need not use 2 Xib's. Please go through the following links :-

[Easiest way to support multiple orientations? How do I load a custom NIB when the application is in Landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496554/easiest-way-to-support-multiple-orientations-how-do-i-load-a-custom-nib-when-th/2496719#2496719)

[Different Xib's for Potrait and Landscape mode for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756903/different-xibs-for-potrait-and-landscape-mode-for-ipad)

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/30/orientation-change-tutorial-change-the-view-when-the-orientation-changes/

Also ios 6 offers new methods like shouldAutoRotate etc. You might want to go through them too.

Comment: so i need to use two views for each nib file

Comment: sry i am not asking you about iphone and ipad i am asking you for different orienattions

Comment: is it possible with out 2 xibs or with out 2 views ?

Comment: now i got it, with the help of struts and springs we can maintain with single view

Comment: @siva good work .... Now if this answer helped kindly upvote or correct accordingly....

Comment: i have some small doubts if ia add some thing programatically i know there are resizing masks we have to use them for each subview,and if i want to change some buttons height i will do it in - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{} i will do in this but for my project the orientation is not working

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return YES;
}
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
       
    }
    else
    {
       
    }
}
these not  called while my view is loading

Comment: my project is tabbar controller based and is there any problem for this

Comment: are you using ios 6 ? In that case they will not be called be see the latest delegates for ios 6 and add your conditions in them...

Comment: the view as appearing in landscape mode in nib file is not apppearing when i run the project, in my project i have mainwindow.xib file is there any problem with this

Comment: Please check the status bar orientation in the appdelegate to see in which orientation your app will launch....

Comment: my app is lauching in portriat mode only,because i keep portriat mode in info.plist file of my target settings. but how to check staus bar orientation in appdelegate file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32921/discussion-between-ironmangill-and-siva)

Comment: still iam not getting in ios 5 but it is fine in ios 6